# disable UIAppearance-API happen on RemoteViewControllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6, uiappearance

So i am styling all my views using the apprearance api.
F.e. i style my `UINavigationBar` using:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navigationBarBgImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

i want to use the advantage of the appearance api of styling all my `UINavigationBar`s in one single place (because i have multiple of them), so i don't want to do some subclassing only because of styling reasons.

i also popup some `MFMessageComposeViewController`s and a `SLComposeViewController` to post to imessage or facebook.

my problem here is, if i try to select albums on facebook or select contacts on imessage modalview, this happens:

[image]

see the recursive description of the imessage modal view:

```
$0 = 0x1f1f1320 <UIWindow: 0x1e5c8900; frame = (0 0; 320 568); layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x1e5c8a00>>
   | <UILayoutContainerView: 0x1e592860; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x1e592910>>
   |    | <UINavigationTransitionView: 0x1f1c88a0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x1f1c8960>>
   |    |    | <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x1f1ee090; frame = (0 20; 320 548); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x1f2f9560>>
   |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x1f2f3d20; frame = (0 0; 320 548); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x1f2f3d80>>
   |    |    |    |    | <_UISizeTrackingView: 0x1f2effd0; frame = (0 0; 320 548); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x1f2f00b0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <_UIRemoteView: 0x1f2f01e0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); transform = [0.5, -0, 0, 0.5, -0, 0]; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayerHost: 0x1f2f0330>>
```

any ideas whats the best to switch back there to default mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is really to subclass one thing or the other. Otherwise you'll be undoing styles everywhere. I'll do it in one of two ways:

One is to subclass `UINavigationController` and style the `UINavigationBar` contained by that class:

```
UINavigationBar *navigationBarProxy = [UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyNavigationController class], nil]; // 
[navigationBarProxy setBackgroundImage:navigationBarBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
// and so on
```

Another method is to subclass `UINavigationBar` instead, set the appearance for that class, and instantiate your `UINavigationController` this way:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[MyNavigationBar class] toolbarClass:nil];
// navigationController now has a navigationBar of your preferred type
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, possible solution is set navigation bars to theirs original tint color with `[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[SLComposeViewController class]] ...`

Comment: poorly, this doesn't work with this `RemoteViewController` thing in ios6. nothing changes if i use `appearanceWhenCointainedIn`.

Comment: @choise Ok then, what if you create a subclass of UIViewController and change appearance of navigation bars which are contained in this view controller only?

Comment: then, i see no reason in using uiappearance-api if i need to subclass something to add a style. then i could also subclass the navigationcontroller itself and add the style to it directly. i don't want this because i have several of them and i thought, there must be a way for this.

Comment: If you subclass UIViewController, you can simply replace in your view controllers' headers UIViewController with MyViewController (add MyViewController.h into .pch file, then ctrl+shift+f -> Replace -> ": UIViewController" => ": MyViewController") and then use UIAppearance as I suggested. In case of subclassing UINavigationController you'll have to override viewWill/DidAppear, probably replace classes in Interface builder, etc.

Comment: okay i get it. not a really elegant solution but it would work. thanks

Comment: Well, it seems that UIAppearance is not "UIRemoteView"-ready yet, so, it's probably a bug. If so, we can't fix UIKit, so workaround is a way to go. BTW, have you already filled a bug on apple's bug tracker? If no, I'd recommend you to do so: https://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same problem and, worse, it was causing my app to crash for any of the XPC/UIRemoteView based controllers, including SLComposeViewController and MFMailComposeViewController.

My solution is to use this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[RootViewController class], nil] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

instead of:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

where RootViewController is whatever you've named the UIViewController that contains all of your app's subviews.

It doesn't work for everything (depends on how a controller ends up in the hierarchy) but, hey, it's something.